# How can I create a shortcut to Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features repair for "Apple mobile device support?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, repair

I've had ongoing problems with iTunes not recognizing my iPhone, after numerous uninstalls and reinstalls and a bit of other trouble shooting I've found the easiest option is to exit iTunes, unplug the iPhone and then go to `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` find `Apple Mobile Device Support` and then click `Repair`

Is there anyway of creating a single link to do just that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Iszi's answer helped I decided to have a bit of a look as to how programs register themselves with appwiz. It seems it's in the registry so I found

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shell\Repair\command
```

With a default value of

```
"%SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe" /f "%1" %*
```

I'm not sure that the google tols me the `/f` is for repair and I guessed that the `%1` is for the msi.

I then found "Apple Mobile Device Support" in

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\5AC59C5E5654D9B479DE5080D8776541
```

Poking around there I found the path to the msi and created a short cut to

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe /f "C:\ProgramData\Apple\Installer Cache\Apple Mobile Device Support 3.3.1.3/AppleMobileDeviceSupport64.msi"
```

It seems to work well enough so far, I expect a similar process will work for other applications too

Answer (score 1):

While not a full solution, a shortcut to "appwiz.cpl" will get you directly to the "Programs and Features" screen.

Good luck finding a way to shortcut the final step.  If there is one, it will probably include some third-party software, which I personally prefer to avoid.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, actually it caused me to wonder how appwiz finds the items in its list, more details below